# C++Builder 10.4: how to turn off indent lines?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I can't find the option In Tools/Options.  How to turn this off?

[image: How to remove the vertical lines in the red box]

Comment: Assuming you speak about the code editor, I can't say for sure in 10.4 but in 10.1 it is: Tools - Options, then Editor options - Source option, then untick Auto indent mode

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Source_Options

Comment: I have turned off Auto indent mode in 10.4 for C/C++ and I have C++ code but I still see the vertical indent lines.

Comment: @jsmith please [edit] your question to provide a screenshot of what you are seeing, and point out what you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auto-indent feature applies when you are editing or entering new text. The file(s) are displayed according to the text they contain - so if your existing file contains spaces or tabs before the actual identifiers etc (ie there are spaces before "for" in your example) these will always be displayed.